# Symfony form & Ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony4

I am working on Symfony 4.4.

To refresh a table, users select three options with an input:

- InProgress
- Finished
- All

Then they must press a validate button.

I want to improve the use of this page by automating the refresh of the table.

Currently on my model I have AJX which allows me to retrieve the value of my entry:

```
   <script>
    $(document).on('change', '#campagnes_tel_isAttending', function () {
        $('#flash').remove();
        let $field = $(this)
        let $preselect = $('#campagnes_tel_isAttending')
        let $form = $field.closest('form')
        let data = {}
        data[$field.attr('name')] = $field.val()
        console.log(data)
        // On soumet les données
        // $.post($form.attr('action'), data).then(function (data) {
        //     // On récupère le nouveau <select>
        //     $('#planningsms_client_label').val($(data).find('#planningsms_client option:selected').text());
        //     let $input = $(data).find(target)
        //     // On remplace notre <select> actuel
        //     $(target).replaceWith($input)
        // })
    });
</script>
```

I am now stuck because I cannot figure out how to get information back to my Controller, allowing me to modify a PreSelect variable with the value of the input and change the structure of the SQL query.

Create a route? Call a route in an Ajax POST?
Use this route in my Controller?

I think it's more or less that, but on the other hand I have no idea how to implement it.

EDIT :

It has moved forward a bit.

I manage to recover the data of the change of the input in my controller.

On the other hand I try to recall the function which will allow me to make a new SQL query with the selected filter, but that does not seem to work.

Ajax :

```
    <script>
        $(document).on('change', '#campagnes_tel_isAttending', function () {
            $('#flash').remove();
            let $field = $(this)
            let $preselect = $('#campagnes_tel_isAttending')
            let $form = $field.closest('form')
            let data = {}
            data['isAttending'] = $field.val()
            console.log(data)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/campagnestel/ajax",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And function in my controller :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/ajax", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function testAjax(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'status' => 'Error',
                'message' => 'Error'),
                400);
        }

        if(isset($request->request)) {
            $preSelect = $request->request->get('isAttending');

            return $this->queryFollowingFilter($preSelect);
        }

//        return $this->queryFollowingFilter($preSelect);
        return  new JsonResponse(array(
        'status' => 'OK'),
        200);

    }
```

Error :

```
The controller must return a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object but it returned an array
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states:

> The controller must return a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object

A `JsonResponse` meets that requirement and suits your needs. Try this:

```
    if($request->request->has('isAttending')) {
        $preSelect = $request->request->get('isAttending');

        return new JsonResponse(
          $this->queryFollowingFilter($preSelect),
          200
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thxx!

It works, on the other hand I have the data in my Console, but I cannot display them when refreshing the page.

Sorry, I'm really starting out in Ajax.